# How to avoid global variables when different functions need data from database call. (JS)

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I'll try to explain the title (-;

I'm making an app. It calls a database in the backend.
The app also collects user information on different screens. They need to be combined with the data from the backend in different ways and give an output to the user.

I  want to call the db once and not from every function. So now, on the 'init' I define a lot of global variables.
I know* that all this global variable stuff is no a good idea. But what is?

*)have read

Comment: Define yourself public module or any interface that will encapsulate your variable. This won't be more secure but it's cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where a JavaScript library may serve you well. Frameworks such as React allow you to set up ways of handling different models such as the user model you describe and making it easier to work with each model throughout the app

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@finalfreq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4574285/finalfreq)' i see there are a lot of frameworks. And also, it will take a while to learn and work with them. But i'm glad i don't have to search anymore within Javascript itself. (-;